# Notepad++ default FileChooser view type

Tags: notepad++

Often when I am working on a bunch of files in Notepad++, I need to open the most recently modified file out of many in a log directory.  I find that I need to get to the 'Open' dialog and then change the view type to 'Details' and then sort on the Timestamp column.

To reduce the number of clicks , I wonder if there is a way to default the 'Open' File Chooser dialog to use the 'Details' view instead of the 'List' view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The free for home Users [Direct Folders](http://www.codesector.com/directfolders.php) product will solve the problem in a general way for all open dialogs.

Here is what it says:

> Direct Folders actions when the file
>   dialog opens:
>
> - Resizes the file dialog box.
> - Sets the custom files view mode and sort order.

Comment: Though not perfect (I need to have DirectFolders running for the customization to work), it does solve the problem.  Accepting based on that.  Thanks.